# How to implement Global Strings C#

Tags: c#

I have lots of global read only strings (around 100) that I am using in my application that will never change. I have been trying to think of the best solution that is easy to code and doesn’t have too much impact on performance. I need the strings to be used throughout the application like the example below, where Relationship is just a category in which the value is grouped and Alternate is the string value itself.

```
Relationship.Alternate
```

I have thought of creating static classes with static read only fields, static classes with const fields, implementing a Singleton pattern and even creating and parsing enums in a helper method. Can anybody provide some good advice on the best way to tackle this problem.

Comment: what is the purpose of the strings? in which contexts are they used? these factors may well influence the best choice of solution

Comment: 9 Questions, 26 answers, 0% acceptance?

Comment: Sorry forgot to accept solutions from my other questions. Have now put this right. Thanks psasik

Comment: I want to create strongly typed objects that represent the strings so that the strings are located in one place in the app and that there are no spelling mistakes which the compiler will not pick up. The strings are all uses as XML Element Attributes used to extend the Syndication classes used to create an ATOM 1.0 feed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using [resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f45fce5x.aspx)?

They are typed, easily accesible from your code at run-time, easily editable without need to recompile, and support any string content (i.e. not like enums, which only support identifier-like strings).

For example, you can add a resource file named `GlobalStrings.resx` to your C# project, and then add a string named `Relationship_Alternate` to that file. You can type any value you want for that string. In code, you would access the string value as:

```
GlobalStrings.Relationship_Alternate
```

Since those are identifiers validated at compile-time, you can guarantee that all your strings will load successfully at run-time.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I would like to keep it in an assembly as this will be used by multiple projects. Sorry should have specified this in my question.

Comment: You can compile resources into your assembly. In fact, "embedded resource" is the default build action in Visual Studio. Your strings will be embedded into your EXE or DLL.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont u put them in enum which can make it memory efficient as well as readable along with less error prone

Answer (score 1):

if they are going to be set at compile time you can try putting them in appSettings (in your web.config or app.config). This would typically apply for connection strings etc. If they are going to be set at run time, depending on some other value, you can go with static class & static read only fields

Edit:If you want them strongly typed, you can also use settings file . see [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a resource file. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f45fce5x.aspx) or solution B in this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Localization.aspx).